# how to reduce as much as possible the bootleneck in autoencoder?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

dears

i have the following code:

```
inpt = Input(shape=(160,1))

# Input is 160 samples, 20 ms for sampling rate of 8 kHz
# Of course speech can be wide-band. One should take care then

conv1 = Convolution1D(512,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(inpt)
conv2 = Convolution1D(128,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='valid')(conv2)


conv3 = Convolution1D(256,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(pool1)
conv4 = Convolution1D(256,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv3)
pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='valid')(conv4)


conv5 = Convolution1D(256,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(pool2)
conv6 = Convolution1D(128,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv5)
pool3 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='valid')(conv6)


conv7 = Convolution1D(128,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(pool3)
conv8 = Convolution1D(64,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv7)
pool4 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='valid')(conv8)


conv9 = Convolution1D(32,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(pool4)
conv10 = Convolution1D(16,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv9)
############################# EXTRA 
conv10 = Convolution1D( 8, kernel_size = (3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv10)
pool4 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (2), padding='same')(conv10)
conv10 = Convolution1D( 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
encoded = Convolution1D( 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv10)
#############
```

the bottleneck here has length 6920 if the input is 27000 signal

I want to reduce the bottlenack into only 400 , how to do that , the amendement sould start from the part **extra**
I tried to add extra conv and pool but the length can't less than 6920.

Comment: @furcifer could you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways you could get the length you want:

1. Increase the pooling sizes along the way:

   pool = MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (4))(prev) # or you could use higher numbers
2. Use VALID padding in Conv and Pool layers:

   pool = MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (4), padding='valid')(prev)

   conv10 = Convolution1D( 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='valid')(prev)
3. You could also use higher stride sizes in Pool and Conv layer

   pool = MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (4), strides=4, padding='valid')(prev)

   conv10 = Convolution1D( 8, 3, strides=4, activation='relu', padding='valid')(prev)

Comment: I receive the following error after applying the option 3:
**Error when checking target: expected model_14 to have shape (96, 1) but got array with shape (160, 1)**

Comment: i change the upsampling to 4 , i get the following error also **ValueError: Error when checking target: expected model_18 to have shape (192, 1) but got array with shape (160, 1)** @Bashir Kazimi

Comment: you have not included your decoder code. I suggested a general idea to reduce dimensions, but you have to adjust it so that you can get the same size output as input for your model to work.

Comment: ```
input_decoder = Input(shape = (1, 4) )

upsmp1 = UpSampling1D(size=2)(input_decoder)

conv11 = Convolution1D( 4, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upsmp1)

upsmp1 = UpSampling1D(size=4)(conv11)

conv11 = Convolution1D( 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upsmp1)
conv12 = Convolution1D( 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv11)
pool4 = UpSampling1D(size=4)(conv12)
conv10 = Convolution1D( 8, kernel_size = (3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
```
@Bashir Kazimi

Comment: Based on your question, and your recent comment, I understand you want to reduce the output of your encoder to have a shape of (1, 4). Then upsample your decoder outputs to have the same shape as the input to encoder, I created a model for this and added it as an answer

Comment: That great, how could you do that, whould you please explain how to calculate elements in the middle? I tought that the decoder must be symetric, isn't it? please explain. and thanks again so much @Bashir Kazimi

Comment: since the code source is now available, now the dimention is 692 can i reduce the bottleneck to only < 200 elements? @Bashir Kazimi how do i calculate that?

Comment: The decoder does not HAVE to be symmetric. You could have longer (with many layers) encoders, and shorter decoders or vice versa. I just played around with the parameters I suggested earlier, increasing pool size for example, to get desired sizes. Currently, the bottleneck is only 4 elements , i.e., (1, 4) but you can play around to change that.

Comment: the size now is reduced from 28000 to 692, can i get less than 200, it is vital for me. 

please how did you make calculation to get 200 and 160 at the output??  @ Bashir Kazimi

Answer (score 1):

I created a draft for you as follows:

1. an encoder taking inputs of shape (batch_size, 160, 1), outputting vectors of shape (batch_size, 1, 4)
2. a decoder taking inputs of shape (batch_size, 1, 4), same as encoder output
3. a combined encoder_decoder model

The encoder:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, UpSampling1D
import tensorflow as tf
inpt = Input(shape=(160,1))

# Input is 160 samples, 20 ms for sampling rate of 8 kHz
# Of course speech can be wide-band. One should take care then

conv1 = Convolution1D(512,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(inpt)
conv2 = Convolution1D(128,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='valid')(conv2)


conv3 = Convolution1D(256,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(pool1)
conv4 = Convolution1D(256,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv3)
pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='valid')(conv4)


conv5 = Convolution1D(256,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(pool2)
conv6 = Convolution1D(128,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv5)
pool3 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='valid')(conv6)


conv7 = Convolution1D(128,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(pool3)
conv8 = Convolution1D(64,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv7)
pool4 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=6, strides=None, padding='valid')(conv8)


conv9 = Convolution1D(32,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(pool4)
conv10 = Convolution1D(4,3,activation='relu',padding='same',strides=1)(conv9)
encoded = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3)(conv10)

encoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inpt, outputs=encoded)
encoder.summary()
```

The decoder:

```
input_decoder = Input(shape = (1, 4) ) ############# 
upsmp1 = UpSampling1D(size=2)(input_decoder) 
conv11 = Convolution1D( 4, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upsmp1) 
upsmp1 = UpSampling1D(size=8)(conv11) 
conv11 = Convolution1D( 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upsmp1) 
conv12 = Convolution1D( 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv11) 
pool4 = UpSampling1D(size=10)(conv12) 
conv10 = Convolution1D( 1, kernel_size = (3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4) 
decoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_decoder, outputs=conv10)
decoder.summary()
```

The combined encoder decoder:

```
encoder_decoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inpt, outputs=decoder(encoded))
encoder_decoder.summary()
```